# Start GIFs in a paused state

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react native app with a page of GIFs for educational purposes (ASL Tutorials).

When I navigate to the page all of the GIFs are playing simulataneously.

I want to know of a way to ensure all of the GIFs are in a paused state, and only begin playing when tapped/clicked, if possible.

Comment: One way I can see this being done is by replacing the gif with images and once the image is clicked, you set the visibility of the corresponding gif to true, making it's position be on top of the image.

Comment: Thank you for this, not a bad idea.